# Weak symbol resolving breaks SIMD platform specification?

Tags: c++, linker, inline, weak-symbol

Our product consists of two parts:

- a runtime-switching part that is implemented in SSE4.2/AVX1/AVX2, and it determines the actual implementation to use at runtime by `cpuid`. It mostly contains calculation-dense DSP algorithms.
- a fixed part that contains most common logics, such as GUI. By design, it should contain SIMD instructions no newer than SSE4.2, otherwise old machines and Apple Rosseta translator will be unhappy.

However, running the product in a Rosseta-translated Apple M1 machine always raise illegal instruction error on specific operation. Disassembly shows an instruction `vmovsd` which belongs to AVX is called, and it is compiled from an call to `std::complex<double>::real()`. I then find the nearest cpp file in call stack, and disassembled the object file compiled from it, especially those function implementations of `std::complex<double>` types, but did not find `vmovsd` in it.

I strongly suspect that this issue is caused by resolving `inline`ed weak symbols, and it is resolved to an AVX-enabled compilation unit. At least, theoretically it is possible to occur. So is there any way to "separate" compilation units that have different SIMD version?

Comment: just don't enable support for those architectures when compiling those files?

Comment: @AlanBirtles It occur at link time, the 256bit SIMD calls is "fetched" from other parts of the whole project.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and include the compiler command line and versions

Comment: @AlanBirtles Actually I have solved this issue following the thought of preventing weak symbol resolving. I don't want to spent time to make an exact small reproducible example, as the behavior of inline-ing and symbol resolving is not quite determinant.

Comment: As the question has been closed, I post my resolve on comment: I make a domestic `MyComplex` type and replaced the using of `std::complex` in the "fixed part" of my library, so it prevents any aliasing weak symbols. However, this is indeed a dirty hack, as there are potentially other similar issue that occur outside `std::complex` type. I think a possible ideal resolve is to make "dynamic" parts into individual dynamic libraries, so implementations of multiple inline functions of different SIMD archs are completely separated at link time.